# how to fix this command?

Tags: centos

[image]

What right package source need to download?

Comment: Please avoid posting graphical screenshots to explain your problems. Copy and paste of the text is usually more useful.

Comment: Also, see [This discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876875/how-to-make-rpm-auto-install-dependencies) to see if you can use the same methododology.

Answer (score 0):

Do you not read your error messages? "FAILED DEPENDENCIES" --- "libgnutls"

You need gnutls, which is a very common Linux package. Find the package name for your distribution, and install it.

Comment: which package is rightest for me in http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libgnutls.so.26(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit) ; http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libgnutls.so.26()(64bit)

Comment: please help, too much same name on website download.

Comment: @sukihinata You need to find this for YOUR distro, as I said. I can't say what it is for rpm, or whatever package manager you use. Nearly every one will have a different name. For example with gentoo in portage its just "gnutls". In apt / rpm / yum / whatever else, you'll have to find your distro's package name. Google is your friend.